# Como criar varios vetores dinamicamente com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, array

Eu recebo na tela de entrada um valor, e eu preciso construir a quantidade de arrays de acordo com o numero que eu recebi. Exemplo: recebo 64 na entrada, logo preciso criar 64 vetores (arrays)

Comment: Mateus poderia ser mais claro onde quer chegar com isso? Talvez você nem precise criar 64 vetores. Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, seria interessante você dá uma lida no tour http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para entender melhor o funcionamento do site.

Comment: Que doido em velho, eu já criei um também usando Jquery. Porque você não troca o nome da pergunta para: Como criar um algoritmo Round Robin? Além de ajudar bastante gente você terá mais gente para te ajudar. Tente também acrescentar o que já tem feito e se possivel acrescentar até como funciona o algoritimo e o que falta para terminar. Você precisa acrescentar mais detalhes a sua pergunta para torná-la mais interessante.

Comment: Matheus podes explicar melhor o problema? Se explicares melhor o que queres fazer vais ter respostas mais ajustadas ao teu problema. Podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar mais informação.

Comment: Você conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria criar um Array de Arrays.

Este método de uma resposta do [@matthew-crumley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) poderia fazer um vetor com capacidade para um número variável de vetores.

```
function createArray(length) {
    var arr = new Array(length || 0),
        i = length;

    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        while(i--) arr[length-1 - i] = createArray.apply(this, args);
    }

    return arr;
}

createArray();     // [] or new Array()

createArray(2);    // new Array(2)

createArray(3, 2); // [new Array(2),
                   //  new Array(2),
                   //  new Array(2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso é assim:

```
var criarArrays = function(n) {
    var arrays = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrays[i] = [];
    }
    return arrays;
};
```